# replace view element in interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

Is there any convenient way of replacing a view with another in Interface builder?

I find it somewhat cumbersome to have to reset all auto layout constraints when I for example want to swap an UILabel for a UITextView.

Answer (score 5):

The "easiest" way to do this so far is to edit the raw xib file in a text editor and just replace the elements there.

Answer (score 0):

@Erik Johansson

To use Auto Layout with best practise is just add view as its container for group of subviews for avoid reset All auto layout constraints

Comment: It's a workable solution but it adds view complexity and pushes the problem one step down in the view hierarchy.

Comment: yes, but hierarchy is good to for complex UI and its not increase complexity but its make easier to identify UIVIew and its subviews